# In Excel, how do I make a column take on the value of column A if it's not NA and otherwise take on the value of column B?

Tags: excel

I've got 2 columns (A and B) and both sometimes take on NA values. I want column C to take on the value of column A if A != NA and otherwise take on the value of column B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this formula:

```
=IFERROR(A1,B1)
```

Put this in C1 and copy/fill down.

[image]